# Google Merchant Product Feed not Accepting my Feed

Tags: c#, gdata, google-shopping-api

I am working with the GData api to import products to my merchant feed.  The code is as follows:

```
List<ProductEntry> newEntries = new List<ProductEntry>();
                    foreach (Product prod in ent.Products.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted && i.IsDisplayed && i.Price > 0))
                    {
                        newEntries.Add(prod.GetNewEntry());
                    }
                    string GoogleUsername = "nope@gmail.com";
                    string GooglePassword = "*****";
                    ContentForShoppingService service = new ContentForShoppingService("MY STORE");
                    service.setUserCredentials(GoogleUsername, GooglePassword);
                    service.AccountId = "*******";
                    service.ShowWarnings = true;
                    ProductFeed pf = service.InsertProducts(newEntries);
                    r.Write(pf.Entries.Count.ToString());
```

This code is returning to me 1 entry, rather than the 400+ it should, and that 1 entry is empty with no error or warning info.  Nothing shows on my merchant center dash.  Any ideas on what might be occurring here?

OR - how can I get more details on what is going on?

Comment: what version of the API are you using? seems like an out dated version, migrate to v2 and you need to use OAUTH 2.0 ,if you want a sample i would be glad to show you

Comment: I would love a link to some sample code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all [create a service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) on Google Developers
  Console if you don't have one already.
- NuGet package [Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2/)

after you do whats mentioned on the link you'll get

- a ClientId
- a ClientSecret

those we will be using to authenticate.

```
 var credentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets() { 
                    ClientId = "yourclientid", 
                    ClientSecret = "yourclientsecret" },
                new string[] { ShoppingContentService.Scope.Content },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

  //make this a global variable or just make sure you pass it to InsertProductBatch or any function that needs to use it
  service = new ShoppingContentService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = "Your-app-name"
        });
```

Now for the insert part:

```
private async Task<List<Product>> InsertProductBatch(IEnumerable<Product> products, ulong merchantaccountid)
        {
            // Create a batch request.
            BatchRequest request = new BatchRequest(service);

            List<Product> responseproducts = new List<Product>();

            foreach (var p in products)
            {
                ProductsResource.InsertRequest insertRequest =
                    service.Products.Insert(p, merchantaccountid);
                request.Queue<Product>(
                         insertRequest,
                         (content, error, index, message) =>
                         {

                             responseproducts.Add(content);
                             //ResponseProducts.Add(content);

                             if (content != null)
                             {
                                 //product inserted successfully
                             }
                             AppendLine(String.Format("Product inserted with id {0}", ((Product)content).Id));

                             if (error != null)
                             {
                                 //there is an error you can access the error message though error.Message
                             }

                         });

            }

            await request.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            return responseproducts;
        }
```

And thats all to it.

Comment: What nuget package do I install to get these classes?

Comment: Believe it or not I am still having problems :(

Comment: give me a second to simplify my code, then ill start one